# Bash script MySQL connection and query via variable

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, centos

I have a bash script with a variable for mysql connection details and a variable for the query I want to run...

```
#!/bin/bash
#listed in the for loop are query numbers = names
declare -a array=(
"1=Unprocessed===\"select count(*) from db where test='unknown'\""
"2=Total===\"SELECT count(*) FROM db\""

)

sqlconnection=$"/usr/local/bin/mysql -u user -passwd -h xx.xx.xx.xx -se"

for i in "${array[@]}";
do

#map s=selection n= name q=== sql query
s=$(echo "$i" | awk -F "=" '{print $1}')
n=$(echo "$i" | awk -F "=" '{print $2}') 
q=$(echo "$i" | awk -F "===" '{print $2}') 

$sqlconnection \("$query"\)
done
```

while I can get the sql connection and query to echo out it doesn't actually run the query! - there's gotta be something I'm missing :)

Comment: `$query` -> `$q`?

Comment: FML - yes that was part of the problem hehe thanks for pointing that one out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqlconnection` should be a function, not a string. Also, you don't need to quote the entire command in each `array` element; quoting `$q` when you call your function is sufficient.

```
declare -a array=(
  "1=Unprocessed===select count(*) from db where test='unknown'"
  "2=Total===SELECT count(*) FROM db"
)

sqlconnection () {
  /usr/local/bin/mysql -u user -passwd -h xx.xx.xx.xx -se "$@"
}

for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    IFS== read s n _ _ q <<< "$i"
    sqlconnection "$q"
done
```

Comment: can you explain what the for loop is doing?

Comment: The loop is the same as in your question. I just replaced the various calls to `awk` with a single call to the built-in `read` command. The variables `s`, `n`, and `q` should be the same as before.

Comment: using the sql connection as a function I get this error:

mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql: [ERROR] /usr/local/bin/mysql: option '-e' requires an argument.

almost as if its not getting passed the $q variable

Comment: Check the value of `q` before you call `sqlconnection`. It should have your query, if `array` is defined as I show in the answer.

Comment: ah I was missing the ` "$@"`